# Listing last 5 recent files and move them to another directory

Tags: grep, command-line-arguments, ls, mv, solaris-10

I'm trying to achieve a one line command to list the last 5 new files within a directory and move those files to another location.
By now I can list them, but haven't find the way to move them, any tip?

```
ls -1t *.txt | head -5
```

I have:

```
$ ls -1t *.txt | head -5
record_-_53810.20160511_-_1053+0200.txt
record_-_53808.20160511_-_1048+0200.txt
record_-_53570.20160510_-_1508+0200.txt
record_-_53568.20160510_-_1503+0200.txt
record_-_53566.20160510_-_1458+0200.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pipe to  `xargs`:

```
ls -1t *.txt | head -5 | xargs -i mv {} another_dir/
```

Or use the expansion itself:

```
mv $(ls -1t *.txt | head -5) another_dir/
```

Or even loop:

```
while IFS= read -r file;
do
   mv "$file" another_dir/
done < <(ls -1t *.txt | head -5)
```

Comment: @hectorlerma sorry that was untested. See the update that does work. I added another approach as well.